# Heroku run: command not found

Tags: node.js, bash, heroku

Trying to run a node.js script (after following this tutorial: http://www.spacjer.com/blog/2014/02/10/defining-node-dot-js-task-for-heroku-scheduler/) with `heroku run` but I am getting `bash: payments: command not found` as a result.

Here are the contents of the extensionless `payments` script, which is located in a bin directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

console.log('It works');
```

I believe the issue may be that the script needs to be located in the bin directory within bash but I am not sure if this is the problem or how to do this if it is the problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I had just forgot to push everything to heroku first, it worked fine afterwards.

Comment: Do you get the console.log to your log output if you --tail it?